# How to define a case insensitive Foreign Key relation in Django Models.py?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My models.py looks like this:

```
class UserRoles(models.Model):
    userId=models.TextField(db_column='user_id',primary_key=True)
    loginId=models.TextField(db_column='login_id', unique=True)
    userRole=models.TextField(db_column='user_role')

class Assets(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserRoles,db_column='User',to_field='loginId',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In my views.py, whenever I make an Object:

```
object = Assets.objects.all();
```

The join between Assets and UserRoles is made automatically on the Foreign Key value. However, the field 'user' is in uppercase and 'loginId' is in lowercase. Thus, only the rows with numeric values in loginId are fetched.

How can I change the relation between the Foreign Key to be case-insensitive?
Something along the lines of

```
select * from Assets inner join UserRoles on lower(Assets.user) = UserRoles.loginId;
```

Note that I cannot make changes in the actual database itself (which is in Postgres if relevant).

Comment: Exactly why do you want to do that? Note that converting it to lower *is* not sufficient for a case intensitive match. You would need a `casefold`, but even then, it would also probably make a lookup less efficient.

Comment: Just make the values in the `Assets` lowercase (well casefold).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I need to do that because the implicit join that Django makes on Assets.user and UserRoles.loginId is not working on different case characters. The join only works on numeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Please *don't*, it will likely only create more trouble, and furthermore likely JOINing, etc. will be less efficient. You can convert the values to lowercase with [**`Lower`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#lower):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

Assets.objects.update(user_id=Lower('user_id'))
```

If you for example do this in the shell, or in a data migration, you will convert all values for the `user` column to their lowercase equivalent.

> **Note**: converting both operands to lowercase is *not* sufficient to perform a case-insensitive match. Some characters, like [*Eszett ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eszett) have no lowercase equivalent, but are considered case insensitive equal to `ss` for example (like the word *paßstraß* which is considered equal to *passstrasse*). One should use *casefold* to check case insensitive matching.

Comment: `DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable`
This is the error I received on trying that. Might I emphasize that I am not explicitly joining the columns in any way apart from just setting the foreign keys. The joining seems to happen under the hood.

Comment: @ArpitKubadia: is the "table" of your `Asset`s in reality a PostgreSQL view? In that case, you should update the records of the "root table".

Comment: yes, yes it is. However I do not have edit access to the root table, just view access. Is there anything I can do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ArpitKubadia: no, unless you are implemented some `ForeignKey` yourself, but that would likely be quite error prone. Can't you create a new view, where you apply `LOWER(..)` on the `user_id` column?

Comment: I'll try that out on Postgres. But is there anything else that can be done on Django itself?

Comment: @ArpitKubadia: as said, you can perhaps subclass `ForeignKey`, but that will require some sopisticated altering of the Django ORM code, which will likely require a lot of work, and furthermore it will be hard to "ensure" that it works in all situations.